# <a4j:mediaOutput/> Not working in Tomcat 7 for image rendering

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I'm trying to display an image once it is uploaded using . Once the user upload the image i'm trying to display the image using the below code.
`<a4j:mediaOutput element="img" createContent="#{bean.paint}" value="1"
                                    style="width:275px; height:75px;" mimeType="image/jpg" id="media" cacheable="false">
                                    <f:param value="#{bean.timeStamp}" name="time" />
                                    </a4j:mediaOutput>`
My Java Code is 
     `public Part part;
      //getters & Setters
     public void paint(OutputStream stream, Object data) throws IOException{
     InputStream inputStream = null;
     try {
     inputStream = part.getInputStream();
        stream.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream));
        stream.close();
        } catch (Exception e){

        }
    }`

 My part is containing the file. but i'm getting the bellow exception.
SEVERE: Input error for deserialize data 
java.io.InvalidClassException: Unauthorized deserialization attempt; org.apache.el.lang.VariableMapperImpl
    at org.richfaces.util.LookAheadObjectInputStream.resolveClass(LookAheadObjectInputStream.java:97)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.readExternal(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.readExternal(TagMethodExpression.java:158)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.richfaces.util.Util.decodeObjectData(Util.java:237)
    at org.richfaces.resource.DefaultCodecResourceRequestData.getData(DefaultCodecResourceRequestData.java:97)
    at org.richfaces.resource.ResourceFactoryImpl.createResource(ResourceFactoryImpl.java:337)
    at org.richfaces.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:156)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:643)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.wellsfargo.ecar.common.util.ServerFilter.doFilter(ServerFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Apr 6, 2015 4:06:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path

Is there anything i'm missing. please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade to the latest version where this issue is fixed. Alternatively open your RichFaces jar/zip and find `resource-serialization.properties`, then add "org.apache.el.lang.VariableMapperImpl" to the whitelist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Makhiel. We have following jar files in our project `richfaces-components-api-4.3.4`,`richfaces-components-ui-4.3.4`, `richfaces-core-api-4.3.4` and `richfaces-core-impl-4.3.4`. I'm not sure where we have the `resource-serialization.properties` file. I checked in all the folders. If i should update the jar file to which version  i should update.

Comment: It's in core-impl inside META-INF/richfaces, the latest version of RichFaces is 4.5.4